# indentifier not declared... but im declaring it now?

Tags: 3d, godot

```
func _physics_process(delta):
  climbing()
```

the script editor says:
"the method climbing isn't declared yada yada..

like I'm literally declaring it now...what do you want from godot? what is it that you seek?

I have declared a few dozen things under func _physics_process(delta), then i tried implementing an upgrade for the climbing system... and suddenly godot decided to not let me do it anymore.

I don't even know what am I doing wrong as I'm following a tutorial step by step...

Comment: Sounds like some script didn't load or didn't parse. I don't have enough information to tell you what (it could, for example, be a script you moved that you were loading by path, or it could be a good old parse error) - and then since that script does not parse, whatever was using it also fails - If you are complaining that Godot is being too eager (i.e. you are using a method before declaring it) you could increase `text_editor/completion/idle_parse_delay` in editor settings.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you provided: no, you are *not* literally declaring `climbing()` now, you are only *calling* it.

You need:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
  climbing()

func climbing():
  [code goes here]
```

If `climbing` was declared in some other script, you need to reference the object the script is attached to, eg `$spiderman.climbing()` if `spiderman` is a child node of the current node.